# How to efficiently store my tabular data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I should save the following data in Elasticsearch:

```
  mytypes = {
        'type1': (
            date(2015, 3, 12),
            date(2015, 5, 6)
        ),
        'type2': (
            date(2015, 4, 11),
            date(2015, 4, 14),
            date(2015, 4, 20)
        )
    }
```

I am not sure what would be an efficient data structure in Elasticsearch. For example, I created the following sample data structure for `type1`, however it looks too hardcoded to me. Is there any more flexible way to store this kind of data in Elasticsearch?

```
PUT myconstants
{
    "mappings": {
      "type1": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true
      },
        "properties": {
          "date1": {
            "type":"date"
          },
          "date2": {
            "type":"date"
          }
        }
      } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a single field, and you can index an array to it. So you can put your mapping like this:

```
PUT myconstants
{
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "dates": {
        "type":"date"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

And then add a document with multiple dates:

```
PUT myconstants/type1/1
{
  "dates": ["2017-01-01", "2017-01-02"]
}
```